# Passing in a kwarg failing in 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyword-argument

Still learning Python and having a hard time finding an answer to this...

So I have a library that has the following function:

```
def clone(source, target=None, bare=False, checkout=None,
          errstream=default_bytes_err_stream, outstream=None,
          origin=b"origin", **kwargs)
```

and i'm calling it like this:

```
porcelain.clone(repo_url, path, bare, errstream=errstream,
                outstream=outstream, opener=self._dulwich_auth)
```

which has been working fine on 3.x. I just tried using 2.7 though and am getting

> TypeError: clone() got an unexpected keyword argument 'opener'

Why is this happening? I haven't seen anyone mention anything different about kwargs in 3 vs 2, so i'm confused why im only seeing this in 2.7. What should I be doing different?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the library's function's signature is identical in both versions?

Comment: Yup. I'm actually using the source directly for now.

Comment: Why are you downgrading from Python 3 to Python 2? There are enough differences that you can't really expect compatibility.

Comment: Well, that syntax is perfectly legal in 2.7, so unfortunately there's no quick fix evident from the code here... It may be necessary to provide a [mcve], difficult as it may be to carve one out of a third-party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is dulwich, an implementation of git in pure Python. I looked at the [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich) and noticed that `**kwargs` has been added to `clone` in 0.18.6. So, if for any reason you are using e.g. 0.18.5 on Python 2.7, but you are comparing it with code written for 0.18.6 on Python 3, you are going to see that error.